# Symfony2 not redirecting to app_dev.php - httpd.conf is setup to redirect but not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony, redirect

So I am finding that I have an issue with CSS if I do not use the ..../app_dev.php path to start the app:

The app does not seem to display the newest css file that I have updated. If i manually navigate to app_dev.php and start exploring the app from there, it all works great. Otherwise if I do not manually navigate to app_dev.php, I get outdated css and if I try and change anything in the style, nothing gets changed, as if the CSS has been cached.

Problem is that if I access "localhost" it does not redirect to app_dev.php even though I have the following in my httpd.conf file:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app_dev.php [QSA,L]
```

Is there anything else I need to do to make the redirect happen?

I tried clearing browser and symfony caches. I restarted the pc, restarted the server(apache including) and nothing is changing regarding the issue.

Comment: What is the issue with css here ? Your question is not clear

Comment: @Ko2r, yeah I tried that

Comment: @GeorgiAngelov My guesses. Is your rewrite rule on the correct virtualhost? Is mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: Paste the vhosts config for symfony